# What does "builds upon" mean here?

Tags: meaning

A sentence from [this article](http://www.eater.com/2015/11/24/9788798/chefsteps-sous-vide-gabe-newell-immersion-circulator):

> Think about how Nintendo or Sony builds upon its popular products and the demands of its audience to create new hardware and software.

I found the meaning "be based on" in the dictionary. I don't think it fits here.

Comment: What about Oxford's ["use as a basis for further development"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/build?q=build+on#build__14)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "builds upon" means to improve upon or refine. It still implies current Nintendo or Sony products are based on older ones, but from a current rather than a past perspective.